# App crashes when loading UIWebView in new devices

Tags: ios, uiwebview, iphone-6

I am some days with a problem I can't understand.
My hybrid app communicates with a webservice that returns an encrypted text with the html to render. Then the app decrypt this text and render the WebView with the html. This html use a css file that is embedded in app.
What happend is when I debug by XCode nothing happen, but when I download the same version from App Store, the app crashes when the WebView will load. This happen only in new devices, like iPhone 6 and iPad Mini 3. In oldest devices works fine.
I'm debugging in Simulator and iPhone 6 and any problems occurs.
I tried don't use the css local file but the problem continues.
Another WebView that don't use crypted html works fine.
Do you have any idea what can be?
Should I developer a native way?


Log from device:

```
Incident Identifier: E614B8C5-69FC-4E29-AACE-FEF75D187EA7
CrashReporter Key:   9127443b5b7e252b878fc8c29923f969d5107916
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             process
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C22501DB-99F8-463D-BD49-1D1E8829E1BA/
Identifier:          br.mycompany.app
Version:             1.8.4 (1.8.4)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-08-12 10:20:01.561 -0300
Launch Time:         2015-08-12 10:19:52.189 -0300
OS Version:          iOS 8.4 (12H143)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                             000000000000000000 0 + 0
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000194f4220c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1608
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182bab7f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ba98a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ad52d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
5   GraphicsServices                0x000000018c52b6fc GSEventRunModal + 168
6   UIKit                           0x00000001876d2f40 UIApplicationMain + 1488
7   FAAP                            0x00000001000bf098 main (main.m:16)
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000194f6aa08 start + 4
9   ???                             000000000000000000 0 + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195068c24 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000194f4de6c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000194f3f998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195083c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511d2d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511ceec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195083c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511d2d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511ceec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195083c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511d2d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511ceec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195083c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511d2d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511ceec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  WebThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195083078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511ef28 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   WebCore                         0x000000019196f984 SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*) + 612
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182bf7f68 ___forwarding___ + 436
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182afacc8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 88
5   WebKitLegacy                    0x000000019282b0b0 WebFrameLoaderClient::dispatchDecidePolicyForNavigationAction(WebCore::NavigationAction const&, WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>, std::__1::function<void (WebCore::PolicyAction)>) + 324
6   WebCore                         0x0000000192343448 WebCore::PolicyChecker::checkNavigationPolicy(WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WebCore::DocumentLoader*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>, std::__1::function<void (WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>, bool)>) + 1616
7   WebCore                         0x0000000191979fa4 WebCore::FrameLoader::loadWithDocumentLoader(WebCore::DocumentLoader*, WebCore::FrameLoadType, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>) + 992
8   WebCore                         0x00000001919aef64 WebCore::FrameLoader::load(WebCore::DocumentLoader*) + 268
9   WebCore                         0x00000001919aedf0 WebCore::FrameLoader::load(WebCore::FrameLoadRequest const&) + 1624
10  WebKitLegacy                    0x000000019282938c -[WebFrame _loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:unreachableURL:] + 1712
11  WebCore                         0x000000019262b824 HandleRunSource(void*) + 364
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182bac23c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182bab4e0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 260
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ba9590 __CFRunLoopRun + 708
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ad52d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
16  WebCore                         0x00000001919542e0 RunWebThread(void*) + 464
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fdc4 _pthread_body + 160
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fd20 _pthread_start + 156
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511cef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195083c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511d2d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511ceec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195083c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511d2d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511ceec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195068e0c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195068c84 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182bab720 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ba9674 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ad52d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   Foundation                      0x0000000183a0d4c4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 312
6   Foundation                      0x0000000183a6780c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92
7   FAAP                            0x00000001000e12c8 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:171)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000183af5db4 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fdc4 _pthread_body + 160
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fd20 _pthread_start + 156
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511cef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195068e0c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195068c84 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182bab720 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ba9674 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ad52d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001825b2590 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 436
6   Foundation                      0x0000000183af5db4 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fdc4 _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fd20 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511cef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 11 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195083078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511ef28 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019403cd5c std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 136
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184232574 JSC::BlockAllocator::waitForDuration(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >) + 176
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001840c9588 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 76
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001840c4b9c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fdc4 _pthread_body + 160
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fd20 _pthread_start + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511cef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 12 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195083078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511ef28 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019403ccac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 52
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184372edc JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 152
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184372f80 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 88
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001840c4b9c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fdc4 _pthread_body + 160
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fd20 _pthread_start + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511cef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 13 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195083498 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182bb1124 __CFSocketManager + 668
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fdc4 _pthread_body + 160
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fd20 _pthread_start + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511cef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 14 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195068e0c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195068c84 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182bab720 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ba9674 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ad52d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   WebCore                         0x00000001919884ec WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 284
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001840c4b9c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fdc4 _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511fd20 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019511cef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x00000000000084aa   x3: 0x00000001950bda74
    x4: 0x000000016fd666e8   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x00000001702a66c8  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000023  x13: 0x0000000000000023  x14: 0x0000000000003fff  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0xffffffffffffffc3  x17: 0x00000001948da6b8  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000044000000
   x20: 0x000000016fd66b3b  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x00000001701439d0
   x24: 0x00000001990b0780  x25: 0x000000016fd66b40  x26: 0x00000001990b07c0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x46b2400000000000  fp: 0x000000016fd66b00   lr: 0x0000000194f3d954
    sp: 0x000000016fd66af0   pc: 0x0000000000000000 cpsr: 0x80000000
```

Comment: What does the crash report say? Do you have any stack trace logs? You can only fix the exception if you know what it is.

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "encrypted text".

Comment: Vinod Vishwanath, I haven't crash report implemented in this version. I'll implement in next version.

Comment: @user2903271 You don't have to implement crash report !!!

Comment: zaph, the communication between my app and the web service uses encryption. The web service send an encrypt text that contains the html and my app decrypt this text before load the WebView.

Comment: @AshishKakkad I meant crashlytics. In itunes console I have only a graphic with the number of errors.

Comment: @user2903271 Crash report means when the app is going to crash then you have console in that the crash report should be printed. hope you are getting

Comment: @AshishKakkad I'm not getting.

Comment: You don't have anything appearing in the debug console............????

Comment: @somtingwong When I debug it works fine, only the app store version crashes. I exported device logs and the app crashes in main thread. I'll to edit the post and insert the log of device.